How can I port HttpContext.Current.Request.Abort() from ASP.NET to .NET Core?
Yes, I have a use case for calling this method.
I have created this question because googling this currently doesn't yield fruitful results as far as I can tell.

The equivalent API is HttpContext.Abort. This has the same behavior of closing the underlying TCP connection.
